# Dynamic element created not POSTed

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, getelementbyid

I create an HTML select element dynamically after a user choice is made from another select element. However the PHP script for inspecting the form does not recognise the new element and is indicating it null.

Here is snippets:

some.js:

```
if(document.getElementById(firstselect).value=='somvalue'){
    document.getElementById(gamsDiv).removeChild(gamsElem);
    gamsElem = document.createElement("select");
    gamsElem.id = "FacilityGamsId";
    gamsElem.name = "FacilityGamsId";
   gamsElem.setAttribute("onChange", "updateHidden(this);makeUpdateRequest(arguments[0],this)");                    
    opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text="Select one ";
    opt.value=0;
    gamsElem.options.add(opt);
    .....some other stuff
    .....                           
    document.getElementById(gamsDiv).appendChild(gamsElem);

}
```

The PHP script:

```
if($_POST){
    var_dump($_POST['FacilityGamsId'];
}

result: null
```

Is there any reason why the server post action does not recognise ANY of my dynamic HTML elements from JS script. If I examine/inspect the newly created elements, the name and id are exactly same.

Comment: Is gamsDiv a descendant of the `<form>` element ?

Comment: yes gamsDiv is part of the POST form I am working with. gamsDiv is a div element inwhich I have a select element called FacilityGamsId. When the form is created first time from server, everything has a value and works. When a change is made by user selecting somevalue, a new select element is created. the existing element with same name is removed and the new one is created and added in its place (with gamsDiv.appendChild)

Answer (score 1):

It's not added to the form stored in the DOM of the browser.

This guy was trying to do the same: [dynamic element created not POSTed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414339/dynamic-element-created-not-posted/7414372#7414372)

A solution would be to build the dynamic form server-side -- if it really needs to be client-side, I think you need to manipulate the form (stored in `document.forms`) in addition to the DOM.

Comment: Rijk, can you please provide a lil snippet on how to add such dynamic element to an existing form in an exact position in the form so that its append order does not affect general appearance? ur help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I can't find any tutorials -- which usually means that it should be possible.. so I'm starting to supect there's something else you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Rijk - you probably should say what you are actually trying to do. To replace one element with another, you can use the [replaceChild](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-785887307) method on the element's parent.

Comment: Thanks all, for the ur suggestions, found a way, by looping through the form elements to get the particular div id and remove/replace its content with the problematic dropdown. Much appreciated everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
gamsElem.options.add(opt);
```

[add](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-14493106) is a method of the [select element interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980), not [options](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-30606413) (which is an [HTMLElement Collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#HTMLOptionsCollection) and doesn't have an *add* method). So:

```
gamsElem.add(opt);
```

should fix the issue.
*`Note that gamsElem.add(opt); does not work in Mozilla firefox 6 so I reverted to my old code of gamsElem.options.add(opt).`*

And:

```
gamsElem.setAttribute("onChange",
 "updateHidden(this);makeUpdateRequest(arguments[0],this)");
```

would be better as:

```
gamsElem.onchange = function() {
    updateHidden(this);
    makeUpdateRequest(arguments[0], this);
};
```

though I have no idea what *arguments[0]* should reference.

Here is how this would be done normally (though the button would call a function rather than have a slab of inline code, I've done it that way for convenience only):

```
<form action="">
  <div id="div0">
    <select id="sel0" name="sel0">
      <option>option 0
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>

<button onclick="
  var div = document.getElementById('div0');
  var sel = document.getElementById('sel0');
  div.removeChild(sel);
  sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.id = 'sel1';
  sel.name = 'sel1';
  sel.onchange = function(){alert(this.value);};
  sel.options[0] = new Option('Select one', '0');
  sel.options[1] = new Option('Select two', '1');
  div.appendChild(sel);
  ">Replace select</button>
```

A second option is needed to get the *onchange* listener to fire.

If you want to replace one element with another, create the new element then just replace the old one:

```
<button onclick="
  var oldSel = document.getElementById('sel0');
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.id = 'sel1';
  sel.name = 'sel1';
  sel.onchange = function(){alert(this.value);};
  sel.options[0] = new Option('Select one', '0');
  sel.options[1] = new Option('Select two', '1');
  oldSel.parentNode.replaceChild(sel, oldSel);
  ">Replace select</button>
```

Or you can just replace the options (set the select's options.length to zero and just add the new ones).

Comment: thanks RobG, However I tried you suggestions and still the same problem. by adding gamsElem.onchange = function().... does not seem to work as the new element when inspected does not have an 'onchange' attribute. I am going to try to manipulate the document.forms as suggested by Rijk

Comment: [document.forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064) is read-only, as are all HTML collections. For an element to be part of a form, it only needs to be a descendant of the form. Strictly, a form control can't be a direct child of a form, it must have a block element first, then the controls.

Comment: Thanks all, for the ur suggestions, found a way, by looping through the form elements to get the particular div id and remove/replace its content with the problematic dropdown. Much appreciated everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new element into your FORM tag

Answer (score 0):

Run this code after the DOM is ready, preferably $.ready() in jquery.

and also put the quotes aroun div name ("gamsDiv")